# Add a number variable to the end of an existing variable

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to generate the following variable:

```
$v = $current_user->wpum_field_11;
```

from the following two variables:

```
$a = $current_user->wpum_field_;
$b = $user_id = get_post_meta($postid, 'user-id', true);
```

I have tried a few variations around:

```
$v = $a . $b;
```

... but this is just outputting the number 11.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve but this sounds like a very ill-fated idea full of bugs and headaches when you go to revisit this code. Anyways, `$a = '$current_user->wpum_field_';` should do the trick.

Comment: Any time you find yourself using numbered variables, you almost certainly should be using an array instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this, constructing the complete attribute name programatically.

```
$attrName = "wpum_field_";
$number = $user_id = get_post_meta($postid, 'user-id', true);

$attribute = $attrName.$number;

$v = $curren_user->$attribute;
```

Comment: thank you very much Dez, I just needed to remove "= $user_id" from the second line. What is this technique known as? thanks again,

Comment: @Scot This is called "variable variables"

Comment: I am not sure if it has a concrete name, but it is generating attribute names through variables. I edited my code because you were generating attribute names rather than methods, even though the same approach would work if you want to generate calls to methods of objects programatically.